# Что такое 'сквозная нумерация машин'? (преимущества нотации inet_aton() для сквозной нумерации машин)

Tags: сеть, tcp, терминология, tcp-ip

Человек пишет:

> Можно было бы иметь сеть класса А или В, и сквозную нумерацию машин в ней.

Как понимать данное выражение, и почему для этого лучше всего подходит нотация inet_aton()?

Comment: Ну по порядку значит: 10.0.36.1, 10.0.36.2, 10.0.36.3 и так далее.

Comment: @A K,  данная цитата была употреблена в разговоре про inet_aton(), и её автор явно указывает на преимущества сквозной нумерации машин, при использовании этой нотации IP. Не могли бы вы разъяснить более детально. Мне простл для понимания необходимо это знать.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что автор имел ввиду именно это, но позволю себе сделать предположение:
начальный адрес для сетей класса B - 128.0.0.0, конечный - 191.255.255.255. Если последний адрес перевести в целое число (а `inet_ntoa` как-раз с ними и работает) N, а затем к этому N прибавить единицу - получится число соответствующее адресу 192.0.0.0 - которой является начальным адресом для сетей класса C. Вот та самая сквозная адресация.